# MUIのDatePickerの言語を日本語にする方法は？

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

MUIのDatePickerの言語を日本語にする方法はありますでしょうか？
下記のようなコードを書いたところ、ブラウザに`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'date')`というエラーが表示されました。
`locale="ja"`を削除するとDatePickerは表示されますが、英語表示となります。

```js
/* eslint-disable react/react-in-jsx-scope -- Unaware of jsxImportSource */
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
import { memo, VFC, useState } from "react";
import LocalizationProvider from "@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider";
import DatePicker from "@mui/lab/DatePicker";
import AdapterDateFns from "@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export const TestPicker: VFC = memo(() => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<Date | null>(null);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} locale="ja">
      <DatePicker
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
});
```

各パッケージのバージョンは下記です。

```
├── @emotion/react@11.4.1
├── @emotion/styled@11.3.0
├── @mui/icons-material@5.0.1
├── @mui/lab@5.0.0-alpha.48
├── @mui/material@5.0.1
├── @types/node@12.20.27
├── @types/react-dom@17.0.9
├── @types/react@17.0.24
├── npm@7.24.1
├── react-dom@17.0.2
├── react-scripts@4.0.3
├── react@17.0.2
├── typescript@4.4.3
・
・
・
```

Answer (score 1):

date-fnsのlocaleを用いれば日本語になるかと思います。

```
import ja from "date-fns/locale/ja";
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} locale={ja}>
```